Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics name field issue
I am trying to use Bicep to setup an API level diagnostic for application insights.  This would be the equivalent of going into the portal, selecting the API and Settings and then enabling app insights and selecting the logger etc etc.

Currently I have the following:
resource diagnostic 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics@2023-09-01-preview' = {
  name: 'applicationinsights'
  parent: myapi
  properties: {
    alwaysLog: 'allErrors'
    loggerId: apimLogger.id
    ...

and then followed by a number of variations such as:
name: '${myapi.name}/applicationinsights' (with the parent tag removed)
name: 'appinsights'
Nothing I try seems to work and I get the following error all the time on the name field:
Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/mysubsciption/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/myapim/apis/myapi/diagnostics/applicationinsights' at line '1' and column '1474'. 'The language expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.'
I have spent a long time googling.  It seems the name should be one of 'applicationinsights' or 'azuremonitor' (similar to the options when you enable in the portal) and what I have tried but nothing seems to work.
Any help appreciated!

The language expression property array index '1' is out of bounds., occurs an issue with the structure format in the name field. Have you verified it properly. @Steve


Unable to process template language expressions for resource xxxx at line '1' and column '1474'. 'The language expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.'

As I mentioned in the comments already, the issue might be due to the inappropriate structure format of either name or a parent resource it is referring to.
In order to provide a name field under diagnostics provider, it must be either applicationinsights or azuremonitor. And make sure that the Api resource symbolic name has been given correctly to the parent field under the same resource.
name: `applicationinsights`
or
name: `azuremonitor`

Refer SO worked by me on deploying the logger and diagnostics Api service resources more clearly.
param apimService string = 'newapimjah'
param apiname string = 'apinewjah'
resource apiManagement 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2020-12-01' = {
  name: apimService
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'Developer'
    capacity: 1
  }
  properties: {
    publisherName: 'jahnavi'
    publisherEmail: 'abc@gmail.com'
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
}
resource Serviceapi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: apiManagement
  name: apiname
  properties: {
    displayName: apiname
    apiRevision: '1'
    subscriptionRequired: true
    path: apiname
    protocols: [
      'https'
    ] 
  }
}
resource Insights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02-preview' existing = {
  name: 'newapsjah1'
}
resource apiMLogging 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/loggers@2021-08-01'={
  name: 'newloger'
  parent: apiManagement
  properties:{
    loggerType:'applicationInsights'
    description:'Logging'
    credentials: {
      instrumentationKey: Insights.properties.InstrumentationKey
    }
  }
}
resource apiManagementApids 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/diagnostics@2023-09-01-preview'={
  name:'applicationinsights'
  parent: Serviceapi
  properties:{
    loggerId:apiMLogging.id
    alwaysLog:'allErrors'
    verbosity:'error'
    sampling: {
      percentage: 100
      samplingType: 'fixed'
    }
}
}

Deployment succeeded:



Thanks Jahnavi.  Yes verified properly, ive updated my post with screenshot but i still get the error:
Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxxxxxx/apis/xxxxxxxxx/diagnostics/applicationinsights' at line '1' and column '20821'. 'The language expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.' (Code: InvalidTemplate).  Must be something silly I am doing so have to go over it very closely, thanks again.

Delete the deployment and start a new one by rewriting the code once. @Steve

Just to update.  It was me doing something stupid.  My bicep code for getting "existing" logger resource had the wrong name so when passed to the diagnostic resource "loggerId" property was actually passing nothing.  It would be good if the deployment alerted that existing resources trying to be pulled in failed (pretty sure you don't see this anywhere).  Anyway, thanks again Jahnavi for confirming what i thought should work and now does :-)

Glad it worked. @Steve
